# How to remove line that '0' included

Tags: python

I want to remove the specific data, please, let me know how to make code. I already coded how to change .txt into .csv.

Let me know what I should do to remove line that '0' inclued

Comment: try changing your title to how to instead of do you know how to

Answer (score 3):

I hope you find it useful.

```
data=[]
for line in open('text.txt', 'r').readlines():
   columns = line.split(':')
   if 'error' in columns[0] or len(columns)==1:
      data.append(float(columns[-1].replace('\n','')))

print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with several lines of code (**edited**: question modified data):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: [x for x in row if 'error:' not in str(x)][0], axis=1)
df['result'] = df['result'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if ':' in str(x) else x)
df[df['result'].isna()==False]['result']
```

**Explanation**: First read the ORIGINAL file with space/s as delimiter.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

    df:
    0                           1
0   error:                      0.007302
1   time:                       240.835871
2   evaluations:                12185.000000
3   parameters:                 NaN
4   2.26024234659371134e-04     NaN
5   6.99262803719691711e-02     NaN
6   3.44898647418988432e-05     NaN
7   5.46135549515059243e-02     NaN
8   8.73320929720244749e-02     NaN
9   8.93333608554642590e-03     NaN
10  5.14965100242248744e-03     NaN
11  3.15603139095758239e-02     NaN
12  1.52425084606730654e-01     NaN
```

Now get the values in first columna of a row without "error:" as result:

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: [x for x in row if 'error:' not in str(x)][0], axis=1)

   df:
    0                           1               result
0   error:                      0.007302        0.00730238
1   time:                       240.835871      time:
2   evaluations:                12185.000000    evaluations:
3   parameters:                 NaN             parameters:
4   2.26024234659371134e-04     NaN             2.26024234659371134e-04
5   6.99262803719691711e-02     NaN             6.99262803719691711e-02
6   3.44898647418988432e-05     NaN             3.44898647418988432e-05
7   5.46135549515059243e-02     NaN             5.46135549515059243e-02
8   8.73320929720244749e-02     NaN             8.73320929720244749e-02
9   8.93333608554642590e-03     NaN             8.93333608554642590e-03
10  5.14965100242248744e-03     NaN             5.14965100242248744e-03
11  3.15603139095758239e-02     NaN             3.15603139095758239e-02
12  1.52425084606730654e-01     NaN             1.52425084606730654e-01
```

Let's insert nan in results with a ':' character.

```
    df['result'] = df['result'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if ':' in str(x) else x)

df:

    0                           1               result
0   error:                      0.007302        0.00730238
1   time:                       240.835871      NaN
2   evaluations:                12185.000000    NaN
3   parameters:                 NaN             NaN
4   2.26024234659371134e-04     NaN             2.26024234659371134e-04
5   6.99262803719691711e-02     NaN             6.99262803719691711e-02
6   3.44898647418988432e-05     NaN             3.44898647418988432e-05
7   5.46135549515059243e-02     NaN             5.46135549515059243e-02
8   8.73320929720244749e-02     NaN             8.73320929720244749e-02
9   8.93333608554642590e-03     NaN             8.93333608554642590e-03
10  5.14965100242248744e-03     NaN             5.14965100242248744e-03
11  3.15603139095758239e-02     NaN             3.15603139095758239e-02
12  1.52425084606730654e-01     NaN             1.52425084606730654e-01
```

And get results droping the nan rows:

```
df[df['result'].isna()==False]['result']

0                  0.00730238
4     2.26024234659371134e-04
5     6.99262803719691711e-02
6     3.44898647418988432e-05
7     5.46135549515059243e-02
8     8.73320929720244749e-02
9     8.93333608554642590e-03
10    5.14965100242248744e-03
11    3.15603139095758239e-02
12    1.52425084606730654e-01
Name: result, dtype: object
```

And to avoid writing the '0' user header=False:

```
df.to_csv(f'{f[:-4]}.txt', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: @NandOsan - I edited sample python code part. please, check my writing, and let me know what I should do to remove line that '0' included.

Comment: I'll rewrite the solution

Comment: @NandOsan-Thank you for helping me. Maybe, do you know how to make simple code? I ran python code using your code. But it didn't get result that I hope.ㅠㅠ I want to only remove '0' lines.

Comment: @platanus you will get it without the 0 if you modify the code in this way:     (`df.to_csv(f'{f[:-4]}.txt', index=False, header=False)`). Use header = False

Comment: @NandOsan-Thank you very much. The code well runs in my pc.